# How can I safely get closer to the black hole?

Tags: evochron-mercenary

In the Sapphire sector way at the top side, there is a black hole and right next to it is a jump field.  However, my ship tends to blow up before getting there (that black hole might have something to do about that).  So how can I safely enter the jump area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried:

- Using high power shields and shield boosters
- Passing through with high velocity
- Using jumpdrive near it to reach over 10k
- Redlight jump when you go through gates

I've finally succeeded by jumping to 79900.-2000.72500 from somewhere near the hole. Half of my shield was damaged, and no damage to fuselage. I jumped to somewhere in Talison.

Comment: nice, when you say high power shields and shield boosters, how high are we talking about?  What type of ship were you using?